# How to print txt file with file numbers using I/O?

Tags: java

i am printing a .txt file using the `Scanner` and I want to print the file with line numbers. here is my code. My problem is that the line numbers aren't incrementing.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class List 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    int line =1;
    File f = new File("src/List.txt");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        int num = 1;
        System.out.print(num);
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        num++;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1Bird
1Dog
1Cat
1Elephant
1Tiger
1Zebra
```

Expected Output:

```
1 Bird
2 Dog
3 Cat
4 Elephant
5 Tiger
6 Zebra
```

Comment: you are recreating the int num = 1; each loop iteration.
Put the declaration int num = 1 outside the loop and everything should work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take `int num = 1` and place it out side of the loop...

```
int num = 1;
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    System.out.print(num);
    System.out.print(" "); // Separate the line number from the text
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    num++;
}
```

This way it won't be reset every time the loop restarts...

Comment: Also add single space string, like this, `System.out.print(num + " ");` to separate numbers and words. (outside*)

Answer (score 2):

Your bug seems to be mixing up `line` and `num` in the body of the loop, but I would also recommend you use formatted output and something like -

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
  System.out.printf("%d %s%n", line++, sc.nextLine());
}
```

The format `String` "%d %s%n" describes a number then a space then a `String` and then new-line. Next, perform a post-increment on `line`. Finally, get the `nextLine()` from the `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
int num = 1;
```

because this will ALWAYS set num BACK TO 1 while it hasNext. This is why the line number won't increment.

After deleting that, also delete

```
num++;
```

because there is no more num variable. Replace that with:

```
line++;
```

I hope this helps!